# What's the most portable way to make python3 make insecure (e.g. 3DES, RC4) HTTPS requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, openssl, 3des

for proper vulnerability scanning it's necessary that python3 speaks insecure HTTPS to avoid overlooking a vulnerable website just because openssl wouldn't talk to it because it was still using SSLv3 or 3DES. After all, those old servers mostly also have the vulnerable applications running on it ;) Compiling my own openssl with enable-weak-ciphers doesn't look like a good option because every user of the scanner also would have to do the same.

The OpenSSL 1.1.1 on my system wouldn't talk to these sites using python3 + requests:

```
10000-sans.badssl.com
3des.badssl.com
client.badssl.com
client-cert-missing.badssl.com
dh480.badssl.com
dh512.badssl.com
null.badssl.com
rc4.badssl.com
rc4-md5.badssl.com
subdomain.badssl.com
wrong.badssl.com
```

(I assume there's no way to get this done using requests and pyopenssl without recompiling openssl, so no need to post my code.)

Also this tip didn't work:
http://www.pybloggers.com/2017/02/configuring-tls-with-requests/

This throws this error: requests.exceptions.SSLError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='3des.badssl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:852)'),))

Any ideas on how to get it done without recompiling openssl?

thx
2d4d

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question completely, but have you tried doing `requests.get(url, verify=False)`?

Comment: Long story short, https must find a common cipher to negotiate. When ciphers become insecure, they are removed from the supporting libraries (and underlying OS C binaries). To make this work you are going to have to build a system which is inherently insecure to then audit if a server will respond to an insecure cipher.

Edit: Most vulnerability scanners package their own SSL suite to get around the requirement that the end user have to build an inherently compromised system to use the tool.

Comment: @keanu: That helps for wrong certificates but not for missing ciphers or protocols.

Comment: @James Powis: No, it wouldn't have to a inherently compromised system because I could keep my self compiled openssl in a different location. Also I could use a totally different library than openssl. Also I could configure openssl to not use the insecure ciphers unless really wanted (openssl.cnf: [system_default_sect] MinProtocol = SSLv3  CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1)